# How to keep an application session opened even if I turn off my device?

Tags: android, session, authentication

I want to make an app that needs to login in a server and I want to keep the session opened even if I restart my device (like the Facebook app do, for example).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to authenticate with your server and then store a user authentication token on the device.  Once that's stored locally on the device you use it to authenticate the next time you hit the server rather than a query/response which was used the 1st time.